# function with disjoint supports and transcendental basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $T$ be a transcendental basis of $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q.$ Let $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ be the set of all irrational numbers. It is clear that $T\subset\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q.$ Let $f$ be a function on $\Bbb R$ and define the support of $f$ to be $$\operatorname{supp}(f)=\{x\colon f(x)\neq 0\}$$ Let $g$ be a function on $\Bbb R$ such that $\operatorname{supp}(f)\cap \operatorname{supp}(g)=\emptyset.$ Notice that  it is true that $(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)\cdot T\neq\Bbb R$  where $(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)\cdot  T=\{a\cdot t\colon a\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q,\ t\in T\}.$ Now, if $$f[\Bbb R]\subset(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)\cdot  T \ \ \text{and} \ g[\Bbb R]\subset\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$$ Define $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ for every $x\in\Bbb R.$ Is it true that $$h[R]\subset ((\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)\cdot  T) \cup (\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)\neq\Bbb R?$$

Comment: What is the relevance of the functions $f, g, h$ to your question? Aren't you just asking whether $((\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) T) \cup (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) \neq \mathbb{R}$ in the end? Anyway, the answer is no: $\frac{q}{t} \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ for every nonzero $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and every $t \in T$, so $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) T$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan. Yes you are right. But, I think $(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)\cdot T \neq\mathbb R$

Comment: Ah, sorry, one correction: every element of $T$ and of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is nonzero, so we're missing $0$. But that's it: if $r \in \mathbb{R}$ is nonzero and $t_1, t_2 \in T$ then at least one of $\frac{r}{t_1}$ or $\frac{r}{t_2}$ is irrational, so $r \in (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) T$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan $(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)\cdot T$ will contain any nonzero rational numbers. and it true that $(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)\cdot T\neq\mathbb R$

Comment: *$t_1 \neq t_2$. Yes, my last comment implies that $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) T = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ exactly.